Using Excel function: How to Select Rows based on Max Version Number
I created a formula to filter a list of items if the progress completion of a build is 100% complete. However some items have revisions and then will eventually restart their progress completion.
The issue I'm encountering is that my filter function will pull in all the versions of an item. How would I get the filter function to only return the rows of the latest version. Right now, the filter is basing it off <100% but there are still duplicates of the item #.
The formula I am using: =(FILTER(Table2,Table2[Progress Category]="<100%"))
Example of the raw data:



Item #
Version #
Progress %




1
1
100%


2
1
100%


2
2
80%


3
1
100%


3
2
100%


3
3
90%


4
1
100%


5
1
100%


5
2
80%


6
3
100%



Expected output
(1 item with the latest version and the latest progress %):



Item #
Version #
Progress %




1
1
100%


2
2
80%


3
3
90%


4
1
100%


5
2
80%


6
3
100%



Thank you!

=CHOOSEROWS(Table2,XMATCH(UNIQUE(Table2[Item '#]),Table2[Item '#],,-1))
Or if the table is unsorted:
=LET(x,SORT(Table2,{2,1}),
     i,TAKE(x,,1),
CHOOSEROWS(x,XMATCH(UNIQUE(i),i,,-1)))


I like this answer, particularly due to the length, and it obviously works in this case. However, it wasn't by oversight that I went with my answer below. I've found that Excel runs into errors when using deeply packed Let statements and the newer array functions (ChooseRows, take, drop, etc), compared to Index. I have some examples, of the breaks, it's usually nested arrays in let statements. Unfortunately, the formulas are too long to put in a comment (). But this shorter answer definitely will work, for this answer.

This formula does the following:

Sorts by ID then version
Creates unique list of ID's
Looks up the ID without exact match, which will always return the last version
Returns respective row

I copied your sample data to cell A1
=LET(allData,SORT($A$2:$C$11,{1,2},1),zUnique,UNIQUE(INDEX(allData,,1)),
iPullRow,MATCH(zUnique,INDEX(allData,,1)), HSTACK(zUnique,INDEX(allData,iPullRow,{2,3})))




Also (old-school):
=FILTER(Table1,COUNTIFS(Table1[Item '#],Table1[Item '#],Table1[Version '#],">"&Table1[Version '#])=0)


Thank you everyone for your help on this problem. The option Tom provided worked the best for my workbook! Now i need to tie it to data validation to toggle back and forth between <100% and complete(100%).
